# OpenWeather api returing null values

Tags: android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, weather-api, openweathermap

I am trying to fetch data from openweather api using retrofit2 and Gson but it always return the null value error.

I  tried to debug and the response returned is fine yet it returns null.

Here is my code..

POJO CLASSES was taken from here.
http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

How I am trying to fetch.

API interface

```
public interface Api {

    String api_key = "b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
    String BASE_URL= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";


   @GET("weather")
    Call<Weather> getWeather(@Query("lat") String latitude, @Query("lon") String longitude, @Query("appid") String api_key);


}
```

LoadWeather()

```
 public  void LoadWeather()

    {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<Weather> weatherCall = api.getWeather("12.9716", "77.5946", api_key);
        weatherCall.enqueue(new Callback<Weather>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {

                Weather weather = response.body();
                 String temp = weather.getList().get(0).getMain().getTemp().toString();
                Log.d(TAG,"onReponse :"+weather);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the App Key 'b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22' which is used for 
the examples (**samples**.openweathermap.org).

You have to [subscribe](https://openweathermap.org/api) to get your own API key.

Comment: I am using my own.  I just wrote it so that people can get POJO classes generated from this api.

Comment: Your code shows that you're using `b6907d289......` . You should modify the code in your question into `String api_key = "my_api_key";` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you forgot to include which API you want to use in the URL?
Maybe you need:

```
String BASE_URL= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";
```